# ERROR: no such file or directory trying to create jar file from terminal

Tags: java, macos

I have performed the following steps:

- A single java file called ComputeArray.java, with no specified
  package
- Navigated into the folder containing the program
- Created the class file (and it runs)

The command I am having trouble with is as follows:

- jar cvf computearray.jar ComputeArray.class

And I have tried using a manifest with cvmf and also tried adding ComputeArray.java at the end. I always end up with the same error "no such file or directory

Comment: You compiled `ComputeArray.java`, and have `ComputeArray.class` in that directory?

Comment: Yes, and it runs perfectly with javac ComputeArray

Comment: Did you make any progress on this, @graem? I'm facing a similar issue and don't want to post a new question if there could be an answer here.

Comment: @authentictech IIRC my problem was with my PATH setup, where the javac command was using a different version of java than the jar command.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to specify the manifest file while creating jar file, something like:

```
$ jar cmf Hello.mf Hello.jar Hello.class Hello.java
```

Here is great documentation to Distributing your Application as an executable JAR file: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html

Comment: I have followed the instructions there and received a similar error, only this time it's java.io.FileNotFoundException: ComputeArray.mf (No such file or directory)

Comment: Have you created the file ComputeArray.mf in your directory?
Also in your manifest *Main-Class* property: the package and name of the class with a main method without *.class* extension (in your case just: ComputeArray)

Comment: Yes I have, and I included the empty line below like the guide said to.